# php class returns result with enter sign

Tags: php

so i have this code that gets an aray of rows from database, in order to put it in a

```
class dat{

    public $result;

    public function loadParteneri (){
        global $db;


        $nrcrt = 1;
    $db->orderBy("numefirma","asc");

    $parteneri = $db->get ("parteneri");
        if ($db->count > 0)
            foreach ($parteneri as $partener) { 
                $this->result[] = <<<EOD
<div id="{$partener['id']}" class="row lines">
    <div class="col-md-1">{$nrcrt}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 serie">{$partener['numefirma']}</div>
    <div class="col-md-1">{$partener['tippartener']}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{$partener['cif']}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{$partener['oras']}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">{$partener['nume']} &nbsp; {$partener['prenume']}</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search view-partener" title="Vizualizare"></span>&nbsp;
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash-partener" title="Stergere"></span>
    </div>
</div>
EOD;
        $nrcrt++;
        }


    $db->disconnect();  
    }
}
```

than i call the class like this and send the response as json to ajax:

```
$response = new dat;
    $response -> loadParteneri();
    $response->result;
    exit(json_encode($response));
```

problem is the response looks like this:

```
"<div id="97" class="row lines">
↵   <div class="col-md-1">1</div>
↵   <div class="col-md-2 serie">2 BRUNO MARS</div>
↵   <div class="col-md-1">clientfinal</div>
↵   <div class="col-md-2">RO15165473</div>
↵   <div class="col-md-2">HUNEDOARA</div>
↵   <div class="col-md-2"> &nbsp; </div>
↵   <div class="col-md-2">
↵       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search view-partener" title="Vizualizare"></span>&nbsp;
↵       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash-partener" title="Stergere"></span>
↵   </div>
↵</div>"
```

what am i doing wrong? thanks in advance!

Comment: actually, it works as expected.

Comment: ok, than how can i  make it return only the html without enter sign?

Comment: newline character "\n" is part of html (or any text output), there are nothing harmful in it. How ever you can use str_replace to remove it. Check answer from Bernard.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$result = << EOD
// DIV's etc...
EOD;

$this->result[] = str_replace(["\n", "\r"], "", $result);
```

It is a bit hackish and replaces ALL the newlines in the result (Also between the DIV's).

You may want to consider using templates to separate you HTML and code instead of mixing it.

Comment: Thanks all ! Yes, it would be the best to use a separate template but till now i was using mostly procedural php and it is a bit hard for me to grasp oop. would you give me an example of a template for this particular case?

Comment: @Leonida-AlexandruDiaconu, you could use pure PHP-templates and inculde them, but I would suggest using a library like [twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/intro.html)